# useEffect - prevent unnecessary execution

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I have an **async redux-thunk method**, which it would **perform a validation process on server-side** and update my react-redux global state value - `hasServerError` **accordingly from REST response**, in order to catch the updated value from react-redux state, I am using the `useEffect` method here, for example

```
const hasServerError = useSelector(state => return state.hasServerError );
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const saveButtonClick = () => {
   // validateForm is a redux-thunk method that will send form data to server through REST
   // and update `hasServerError ` to be true if there is error from server response
   dispatch(validateForm());     
}

// when the above validateForm would updated the value of `hasServerError `, this should trigger
useEffect(() => {
   // if hasServerError still false, continue saveFormData
   // otherwise, display a error modal
   if (!hasServerError) {
      dispatch(saveForm());     
   } else {
      dispatch(showErrorModal());
   }
}, [hasServerError, dispatch])
```

This would work well when user clicks the save button, however, something behaved weird that **when the `hasServerError` was set to false from another dispatch, and `saveForm` was being triggered automatically again**, for example, when I load my form data initially, or when user correct their error in form or user clicks cancel button and I need to trigger a method which would automatically reset the global state `hasServerError` to false, when such scenario happens, my `useEffect` automatically triggered with `saveForm`, for example:

```
const textInputChange = (e) {
    if (forceSave) {
       dispatch(clearHasServerError());     // set state `hasServerError` to false, but it triggered the useEffect
    }
}
```

or

```
const cancelButtonClick = () => {
   dispatch(clearHasServerError());     // set state `hasServerError` to false, but it triggered the useEffect
}
```

I understand this happened because my dependency `hasServerError` updated, but how could I only let my `useEffect` to perform the `saveForm` when user clicks button, but not when anytime the state value `hasServerError` becomes **false**?

Should I set another flag when user clicks the button and add that into `useEffect` as **side if condition**? That seems not a wise approach but I cannot figure out any better solution for now...

Comment: How about checking an `event` object inside `saveForm`? `event` should only exist if the button is clicked.

Comment: the `saveForm` was an external redux-thunk method, I didn't find there is an `event` object there...what the `saveForm` does is to fetch from some data redux global state and perform a `PUT` api request to server, it doesn't include any `dom` element..

Comment: Yes, you need to add a local flag indicating that the save button is clicked. and then inside use effect, you can check for that.

Comment: Yes @SagarDarekar, that's my temp solution for now, somehow just feel it's an `ugly` approach...

Answer (score 1):

> how could I only let my useEffect to perform the saveForm when user clicks button

If you want `saveForm` to occur on button click, just add it to the button click handler. If you want to validate on state updates, validate it when a value is changed in your reducer. In general,

```
case "SET_SOME_VALUE": {
    return {
        ...state,
        someValue: action.payload,
        isValid: validate(state)
    }
}
```

or do it right in the component,

```
const component = props => {
    const state = useSelector(getState)
    const isValid = validator(state)

    const handleSave = () => { /* save stuff */ }

    /* do something with the validation */
    return <div className={isValid ? 'validCss' : 'invalidCss'}>Hello World</div>
}
```

Have a button change state and then having a `useEffect` run a side-effect based on that state change can get a little hair with re-renders. If you can do it in a click handler, that's probably best.

Comment: Hi @Yatrix, thanks for sharing your idea! This would work for mostly the `client side` validation, however, my `validateForm` is a service side validation thatwould publish the `formData` through REST in a redux-thunk, that's why I call my redux-thunk `dispatch(validateForm());` in button click - handleSave and I have to use the `useEffect` to monitor the state `hasError` value, as it would update in redux thunk based on my server response.